# How to implement authentication and authorization for web apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-ec2, google-signin

I have been working on a web application. I installed it on AWS EC2 instance. Currently it is available to all the people over the web. However I'd like it be available only for authorized users. Could you please help me on how to implement the google sign in for the app so that only user who authenticate with google sign in can access it.

I had referred to the google sign in for websites doc: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/ . It however talks only about implementing the authentication code but not about how it should be connected to the web app.

Where should I place the google sign in code? is it inside the web app code

OR

Should I create a seperate web page for sign in code and redirect it the AWS/web app server IP address?

Thanks

Arun

Answer (score 0):

Google's API Clients, which will let you implement Sign in Using Google, are hosted on [Github](https://github.com/google). Visit https://github.com/google?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=api and find the repo `google-api-[your_language]-client`. Follow [this tutorial](http://phppot.com/php/php-google-oauth-login/) to get started.